# Set multiple listeners to one method

Tags: java, android

I am learning to develop on android on android studio and I encountered a problem.

I have multiple EditText controls for user info: First Name, Last Name, Address and I want them to behave the same when they are in focus and out of focus.

For example, my emailInput EditText control has "Email Address" as its text property. When the user clicks "Email Address" disappears and if the user didn't add any input and leaves the control "Email Address". This is what this method does:

```
private string emailAddress = "Email Address";
public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean focus)
{
           (EditText) email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailInput);

           if(!focus && (email.getText()).equals(""))
           {
               email.setText(emailAddress);
           }
           else if(focus && (email.getText()).equals(emailAddress))
           {
               email.setText("");

            }

}
```

I have like 20 controls and I don't want to copy and paste the same code and change the variables.

I have two questions: Can I get the id of the control that calls the onFocusChange method so the first line becomes ->

```
 (EditText) ctrl = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.(this.getId());
```

and can I add a new property "Initial Text" to EditText controls so I can get something like this ->

```
      if(!focus && (ctrl.getText()).equals(""))
       {
           ctrl.setText(ctrl.getInitialText());
       }
       else if(focus && (ctrl.getText()).equals(ctrl.getInitialText()))
       {
           ctrl.setText("");

        }
```

EDIT: This is sort of like creating my own control that inherits from the EditText class. I'm just adding an object variable(Initial Text) and a method(getInitialText). Can I create my own control like this and still have the Drag and Drop feature in android studio?

Thanks! :D

Comment: You can create a generic function that takes a control as an argument and simply put that in your `on*` action listeners. In each listener for the specific control you can get the control object and pass it to your function, minimizing the re-pasting of duplicate code.

Comment: That's what the `view` argument is for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour you describe is exactly what the `android:hint` attribute on any EditText does.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:hint

Comment: Thanks so much :D!. This is exactly what I was trying to do.